# Diacritics with drawText in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawtext

We want our app to be available throughout Europe, but have been unable to discover how to use drawText to a Canvas with a string containing diacritics. Characters outside the "English" range are drawn as a rectangle.
Can anyone point us to a source of information on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Our problem was solved when we explicitly created a UTF-8 file containing the text. We used WordPad to update all the files.
This was not an obvious solution, and it feels unnecessary. If anyone knows of a neater software solution, we will be pleased to know of it.
However, we can now make progress with our app:
**Conçu par les étudiants pour les étudiants** et leurs professeurs
and
**Entwickelt von Studenten für Studenten** und ihre Lehrer

as it now says so splendidly on our sample graphs